# How to call a WebService using backbonejs

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am new to backbonejs, and I want to call [this webservice.](http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo)

Will anyone help me how to call this service using backbonejs.

Comment: is your problem solved base on my answer?

Comment: @Dato' Mohammad Nurdin no friend, now only i am trying to do ur answer.

Comment: let me know, ok? i can assist you

Answer (score 0):

Create a backbone model.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url:"http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo"
});
```

Then you can create new instance of the model and [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) it from the server.

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.fetch()
```

Depending on the data you might need to override the backbone models internal parse function. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

Here is a basic fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9cvVv/619/

Comment: Thanks for ur reply friend, but i cant able to get a response. I can able to get response from this(http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting) service.

Answer (score 0):

try this one. put this code into your render function

```
formData = {
    north: "44.1",
    south: "-9.9",
    east: "-22.4",
    west: "55.2",
    lang: "de",
    username: "demo"
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formData,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //success handler
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //error handler
    }
});
this.$el.html(yourViewTemplate);
```

Comment: Its working fine in jsfiddle but while i am doing the same in browser it is showing the error like this.      Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: using ripple chrome extension my friend.

Comment: @ Dato' Mohammad Nurdin friend i used that ripple chrome extension now its showing Access id denied. Is there any solution for this. Pls help me i am struggling a lot.

Comment: @ Dato' Mohammad Nurdin for ur reference see the below jsfiddle example. I would like to do the same in my program also.

Comment: just added library file from jsfiddle instead of my library file. Now its working fine.